# Read from a Barcode Readers

Tags: vb.net

I have an application in vb.net 2013.
I've tried to find a way to read from a Barcode reader.
Is there any library that can help me read from USB Barcode Readers ?

Thank you !

Comment: Most likely the barcode scanner pretends to be a keyboard, so treat it as such. Otherwise it should come with an SDK of some sort to which you should refer.

Comment: @Gserg - A barcode that i's using now , just plug on usb and it's recognized automatically. On notepad I can use the device and the barcode is shown inside notepad document. The problem is that that on my program on a textbox , without writing any line of code , when I use the reader I can see that the barcode is wrote and immediately disappear from textbox.

Comment: @Gserg - is there any way to make the barcode to stay inside the textbox .  And a way to read the barcode in a invisible mode without displaying anywhere.

Comment: Apparently the scanner sends Enter. Make sure your textbox shows multiple lines. To read the barcode without a textbox, handle the keypress event on your form, but I would not call that reliable for keyboard-like scanners.

Answer (score 0):

That's why I like my Barcode scanners to act as serial devices. Most of the ones I've seen you can scan a special Barcode and it will reconfigure itself as a serial device. Then you can use the serial port control and every time something comes in over that serial control you know it's a scanned barcode

Comment: And how you make an USB Barcode reader to act as a serial device ?

Comment: It's depends on the model ... what model do you have